# JSON.NET Deserialization "Hangs" (Mono)

Tags: c#, mono, json.net

mono-core-2.6.4-2.13.x86_64
Json.NET 3.5 Release 8

I call the deserializer and it works - I can see the objects created
(deserialized) but then the deserializer never exits/returns.

```
List<ListEntry> listed_entries =    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ListEntry>>(payload); 
Console.WriteLine("Deserialization complete");
```

ListEntry objects are created, then the program 'hangs'.
"Deserialization complete" never appears.

The JSON payload is 1,938K of:

```
[{"entityName": "Contact", "version": 27, "displayName": "", "objectId": 11446184}, {"entityName": "Contact", "version": 33, "displayName": "", "objectId": 10148760}, {"entityName": "Contact", "version": 35, "displayName": "", "objectId": 12695703}, {"entityName": "Contact", "version": 33, "displayName": "", "objectId": 7575210},
... ]
```

with no trailing newline.  No complex; it decodes to an object of:

```
public class ListEntry
{
  public ListEntry ()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Created ListEntry");
  }

  [JsonPropertyAttribute("entityName")]
  public string EntityName { get; set; }

  [JsonPropertyAttribute("objectId")]
  public int Objectid { get; set; }

  [JsonPropertyAttribute("version")]
  public int Version {  set; get; }     

  [JsonPropertyAttribute("displayname")]
  public string DisplayName {  set; get; }      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem;  in one of the JSON elements there was a "version" attribute of "null".  This, of course, cannot deserialze to a .NET "int".  The exception in the deserialization thread doesn't seem to propagate to the main thread.  Anyway, modifying the serialization object resolved the issue:

```
[JsonPropertyAttribute("version")]
public int? Version 
{  
  set 
  {
    if (value == null)
      this.version = 0;
    else
      this.version = (int)value;       
  }
  get { return this.version; }
}
```

Comment: I just ran into this same thing. I have forwarded the info with a test to the caretakers of Xml serialization.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to work with nullable types:

```
[JsonPropertyAttribute("version")]
public int? Version 
{  
    set 
    {
        this.version = value ?? default(int);
    }
    get
    {
      return this.version;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say this is the proper way. If a property is nullable, it should be possible to set its value to null. Otherwise, the property should not be nullable´.

Comment: @erikkallen: Agree if object's property is nullable by-design. But if it's just int but filled from web, that's why incoming type is nullable and used like I wrote.

Comment: If it's just an after deserialization patch, I would do it with an OnDeserialized callback instead of making the property something it's not.